# Visual Studio Code error can not explicitly assign protected access modifier to a class which is not defined in a namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, namespaces

I code C # in VSCode version 1.63.2 and the problem is;

> class ClassTwo
> Elements defined in a namespace cannot be explicitly declared as private, protected, protected internal, or private protected [test]csharp(CS1527)

I don't have any namespace declared in my .cs file now. At first, I had declared a namespace, then I remove it but the error still persists. What I've tried is to rename the class (it works, with different class name I don't face this problem), then I tried to remove the class file and recreate it with the same name (this did not work). I have a project named "test" with two classes and two .cs files with the same names, one is named ClassOne, the other one is ClassTwo.

ClassOne.cs

```
namespace test
{
    protected class ClassOne
    {
        
    }
}
```

ClassTwo.cs

```
protected class ClassTwo
{
    
}
```

test.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Screenshot of the problem;

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6RaZ.png)

Comment: Can you share some code that you wrote?

Comment: I have added the code and screenshot of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare a `private` or a `protected` class in a namespace. Classes are either `public` or `internal` (except for nested classes). This issue isn't related to VS Code, it's simply the compiler telling you did a mistake.

Quote from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/class):

> Classes that you declare directly within a namespace, not nested within other classes, can be either public or internal. Classes are internal by default.

### EDIT 2

Now that you posted your code we can finally understand what's exactly your issue and provide you an answer.

You're using .NET 5 which is using C# 9 by default. Therefore the answer I wrote down bellow in the first **EDIT** section isn't relevant.

In C# when you don't declare any namespace in a file, your class is by default added to the **global namespace**

> The global namespace is the namespace that contains namespaces and types that are not declared inside a named namespace.

See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/namespace-alias-qualifier) for more information.

Assuming you're correcting the error and changing your class to `public` or `internal`, you can then use it like this

```cs
var myTwoObject = new global::ClassTwo();
```

### EDIT

**I'm keeping this section just because it's useful information but since you then posted your code we can now tell that you're not in C# 10 therefore this isn't the correct answer**

From your comment I now understand that you must have created a .NET 6 **console application**.

By default, console application in .NET 6 are generated with a new template which is valid starting from C# 10

Have a look at the documentation [New C# templates generate top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates)

You can access your class by doing

Quote from this doc:

> The term top-level statements means the compiler generates the namespace, class, and method elements for your main program. You can look at the code for the new application and imagine that it contains the statements inside the Main method generated by earlier templates.

It means even if you don't declare a namespace, it is still generated at compile time. Consider the namespace **implicit** just like [Implicit using directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#implicit-using-directives).

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. My class is not declared in a namespace, as i said in my question, when i remove the namespace, i still get  the error, but if i dont declare any namespace at first, i dont get the error, looks like a bug

Comment: @TheAlp I edited my answer. Please when you post a question on Stack Overflow, try to always include some **relevant code** so we understand better what you mean. Just a text explaining your problem is most of the time not recommended on this wesbite.

Comment: I have changed the question and have added more information based on your suggestion.

Comment: @TheAlp I edited my answer again then. You see, now your question is much clearer with your code than just a bloc of text 